# C# Different result for same input

Tags: c#, string, indexof

My code has an issue with the `IndexOf` method as below:

---

```
string str="NOI THUONG TRTHON ";
int i = str.IndexOf("TRT");  // --> result: i=-1  :( ???
int j = str.IndexOf("TR");  // -->  result: j= 11 :)
int k = str.IndexOf("I T");  // --> result: k=-1 :(  ???
```

---

Could you please help me to explain, how do I get index of string as for var j,k?

Comment: How do I get index of string as for var i,k? (misstake typing)

Comment: I tested your code but everything is working as intended. I got `i = 11`, `j = 11` and `k = 2`.

Comment: Try to delete `obj` folder, clean your solution, try to rebuild and check once

Comment: Image for my result: https://photos.app.goo.gl/MukpMKoqC1wpMxRF7

Comment: see this fiddle => https://dotnetfiddle.net/5S1ztg and carefully watch output

Comment: Is this the *exact* code, copied and pasted? My guess is that in the case you've shown in the screenshot, you've got a non-ASCII character in there which is confusing things.

Comment: Try an IndexOf("RTH") and if you get -1 that will pretty much prove what Jon Skeet is describing.